# How to trigger onSelectionChange only when caret moves but input has not changed?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, events, input

I have an use case in my React Native app (trying to implement mentions) where I need to call a function on the event of onSelectionChange only when the text in the input has not changed but the caret was moved.

At the moment the onSelectionChange function is called when I write as well, but I need it to be called only when the caret was movet without writing anything inside the input.

Is that possible? Sorry I don't really have any code to show for it since I explained what I need, but I did not find anything to check of the caret was moved without adding any new text?

Comment: Maybe just get the current field value inside the handler function, and compare it to the previous one - and if they are equal, just do nothing ...?

Comment: @CBroe onSelectionChange does not have the currentValue when you type a new letter, just the old value unfortunately.

Comment: You probably are going to have to mix oninput with onselectionchange

Answer (score -1):

you should try something like onblur

https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput#onendediting

https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput#onblur

this will trigger when you leave the field, you can write your validation in the callback method.

Comment: unsure what onblur has to do with the cursor moving

Comment: The field is not blurred at any point during this. Really don't understand what the idea would be here.